# Ember data - find out if a record has been saved to the server

Tags: ember-data

I'm running into a situation where I have an ember-data record and I don't know if it has already been saved to the server or not. Is there any way to find out?

(Using ember-data (1.0.0-beta.11) and ember (1.8.0))

Before saving to the server the ID will be something like `9gdh5` so I was initially just checking `isNaN(+record.get('id'))` but unfortunately this fails occasionally when the temporary ID generated by ember doesn't contain any letters.

Searching revealed that ember-data previously used a `_clientId` property but this seems to have gone. Am I missing something obvious or do I need to manually manage a flag saying whether a record came from the server or was generated locally?

Here is some information about my use-case in case it helps to clarify the question...

My app works both on and offline. My custom adapter knows when it is offline and queues requests to LocalStorage to send when online. The user can update records and when the adapter receives this update it needs to know if the record has been synced to the server yet. If so it queues an `PUT` request to be sent to the server when online. If the record hasn't been synced yet we can't do a `PUT` request because we don't know the record's ID (which is part of the URL for the `PUT`). So instead we have to find the locally stored `POST` request and update that instead. So I want  a reliable way to find out if a record has been synced to the server or not...

Comment: As a workaround I'm currently setting a flag in `createRecord` which is never returned from the server. If the flag is present the record hasn't been synced. I thought there would be something like this built in though...

Answer (score 2):

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew

This might be new since this issue was created but I came here looking for the answer so thought I would paste what I found.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if it existed when I asked the question but it sounds like it might work...